# I can not get JsonArray in Ion and mapped Java class

Tags: android, android-json, android-ion

I use the library [enter link description here](https://github.com/koush/ion)

my class and method:

```
public static class Test {
        public String name;
        public String soname;
        public String age;
        public String country;
    }
    private void setData(){
        Ion.with(getActivity())
                .load("http://............")
                .as(new TypeToken<List<Test>>(){})
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<List<Test>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, List<Test> result) {
                        // do stuff with the result or error
                        Log.d("ionmy", e.toString());
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result.get(0).name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

    }
```

in this way I get the data:

```
[{"name":"Vasya","soname":"Pupkin","age":"25","country":"Russian Federation"},{"name":"Iliya","soname":"Strelnikov","age":"43","country":"Kazahstan"},{"name":"Iliya","soname":"Lagutenko","age":"49","country":"Ukraine"}]
```

my error:

```
D/ionmy﹕ com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2
```

and stacktrase log:

```
12-22 07:44:02.138    1015-1015/com.testlist.pavel.transportercity E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.testlist.pavel.transportercity.Fragments.Kitchen_list_of_orders$1.onCompleted(Kitchen_list_of_orders.java:53)
            at com.testlist.pavel.transportercity.Fragments.Kitchen_list_of_orders$1.onCompleted(Kitchen_list_of_orders.java:48)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.handleCallbackUnlocked(SimpleFuture.java:79)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:119)
            at com.koushikdutta.ion.IonRequestBuilder$1.run(IonRequestBuilder.java:217)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$RunnableWrapper.run(AsyncServer.java:171)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I can not correctly configured JsonObject?

Answer (score 1):

The exception indicates a JsonObject is being returned, not a JsonArray (a List).